# Pre Launch Report requires Username Resource ID and Password Resource ID for firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I am using Firebase Authentication in my android app.
I would like to run Google Pre Launch's report test in Play console to identify issues.
As required I am trying to add Test account credentials.
It requires me to enter **Username,Username Resource ID,Password,Password Resource ID**.

[image]
I don't have any issue entering Username and Password for testing account.But what to enter inside Username Resource ID and  Password Resource ID since the layout is generated by Firebase and i don't have their resource ids.